# Array? ArrayList? Don't know which one to use in my case

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I have wrote a program that sorts a file that has ages and names (age, name) in ascending order. I have done this using bubble sort and two arrays, one that stores ages and one that stores names. The problem I am having is that I don't know how many people (ages and names) are going to be on the file so I don't know how big to make my arrays. I was considering using an array list but I don't know if that violates the requirements of this assignment. The requirements are:

takes O (1) space in addition to the provided input array. Your algorithm may modify the input array.

Can I use an array list or does anyone have any other suggestions for how to store my data where the size can change?

Comment: What the requirement basically states that you can only use a constant amount of extra space apart from the input array. You can use `ArrayList` for this.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, you can modify your array, which means you should sort in place